Flutter: How to test what value is being returned via Navigator.pop?
I have written a unit test that checks that my dialog exited via Navigator.pop(). But I would also like to know what value was passed to Navigator.pop() - ie I would like to know that the dialog returned the correct value.
But I can't work out how to do this?
I've found two ways of testing Navigator.pop() - one is to use the MockNavigatorObserver, as per this blog post. One is to use a TestObserver as per this code. In both of those examples, I can spy on the current and previous Route params From the documentation, it seems like the value passed to Navigator.pop should end up in result, but if I inspect the currentResult value on the route object, I get nothing.
Any help would be appreciated!
My dialog code:
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);

I just want to verify that true was passed to pop.
My test code using MockNavigatorObserver:
class MockNavigatorObserver extends Mock implements NavigatorObserver {}
class MockRoute extends Mock implements Route {}

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    registerFallbackValue(MockRoute());
  });

  testWidgets('My test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ListenableProvider(
        create: (_) => authProvider,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: MyScreen(),
          navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
        ),
      ),
    );

    final submitButton = find.text('Submit');
    await tester.tap(submitButton);

    // Verify that a pop event happened
    verify(() => mockObserver.didPop(any(), any()));
    // I'm not sure how to access route.currentResult here but I do it in the below code and get nothing.
  });
}

My test code using TestObserver:
import '../helpers/observer_tester.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('My test',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final List<NavigatorObservation> observations = <NavigatorObservation>[];

    final TestObserver navigatorObserver = TestObserver()
      ..onPopped = (Route<dynamic>? route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
        observations.add(
          NavigatorObservation(
            current: route?.settings.name,
            previous: previousRoute?.settings.name,
            result: route?.currentResult,
            operation: 'pop',
          ),
        );
      };

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      ListenableProvider(
        create: (_) => authProvider,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: MyScreen(),
          navigatorObservers: [navigatorObserver],
        ),
      ),
    );

    final submitButton = find.text('Submit');
    await tester.tap(submitButton);

    // Verify that a pop event happened
    expect(observations[0].operation, 'pop');
    expect(observations[0].result, true);
  });
}

I get the following test failure as a result of the above code:
Expected: <true>
  Actual: <null>

